# How to increase the opacity of div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to animate a div. The opacity of the div should be in a way  finally the it should be displayed in maximum opacity. How it can be done ?

Comment: take a look at : http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: css3 solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cDmkX/1/

Comment: If you plan to use jQuery at all, ever, it pays to spend a few minutes browsing through the complete [list of methods and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/), which gives a one-line description of each. Or even spend an hour or two reading and re-reading through it carefully - an hour doing that today could save you many hours later. Right near the top of the list you'll see the `.animate()` method, which will obviously help with your current problem, but more generally you'll get a very good idea of the types of things jQuery can do so you'll know where to start for the _next_ problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the opacity of the div to 0

```
$(div).css({opacity : 0})
```

Then, use the animate

```
$(div).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000)
```

You can set the opacity in css as well

Answer (score 0):

Using [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/):

```
$('div').fadeTo('fast', .5) // fade div to 50% opacity
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use animate:

```
$('#test').animate({

    'opacity': 1,
    'width': '400px'

},  600);
```